# Nivo Slider does not load on random occasions

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, nivo-slider

I'm facing an ongoing issue on a self hosted wordpressblog where the entire bunch of the image sliders do not load on random occasions. During the non-loading times, the javascript console on Chrome reports these:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'
>   http://www.xxxxxx.com/:3408
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method
>   'jCarouselLite' http://www.xxxxxx.com/:3392

I've pasted the entire footer.php file below where, I believe, the slider calls might be inappropriately configured.

```
    <?php //get theme options
global $oswc_front, $oswc_ads, $oswc_misc, $oswc_single, $oswcPostTypes;

//set theme options
$oswc_flickr_name = $oswc_misc['flickr_name'];
$oswc_google_analytics = $oswc_misc['google_analytics'];
$oswc_footer_ad_hide = $oswc_ads['footer_ad_hide'];
$oswc_footer_ad = $oswc_ads['footer_ad'];
$oswc_featured_duration = $oswc_front['featured_duration'];
$oswc_spotlight_duration = $oswc_front['spotlight_duration'];
$oswc_latest_speed = $oswc_misc['latest_speed'];
$oswc_colorbox = $oswc_misc['colorbox'];
$oswc_footer_menu_hide = $oswc_misc['footer_menu_hide'];
$oswc_share_twitter_show = $oswc_single['twitter_show'];
$oswc_share_digg_show = $oswc_single['digg_show'];
$oswc_share_plusone_show = $oswc_single['plusone_show'];
$oswc_share_pinterest_show = $oswc_single['pinterest_show'];
$oswc_share_tumblr_show = $oswc_single['tumblr_show'];
?>

        <?php if(!$oswc_footer_ad_hide) { //the ad above the footer ?>

            <div class="full-width-ad">  

                <?php echo $oswc_footer_ad; ?>

            </div>

            <br class="clearer" />

        <?php } ?>

    </div><!--end main wrapper dark-->

    </div><!--end main white content wrapper -->

    <div id="footer-wrapper"> <!--begin footer wrapper -->

        <div id="footer">

            <?php if(!$oswc_footer_menu_hide) { //the menu in the footer ?>

                <div class="footer-menu">

                    <a class="home-link" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">&nbsp;</a>

                    <?php 
                    //title attribute gets in the way - remove it
                    $menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer-menu', 'container' => '0', 'fallback_cb' => 'fallback_footer_menu', 'echo' => '0' ) );
                    $menu = preg_replace('/title=\"(.*?)\"/','',$menu);
                    echo $menu;
                    ?> 

                </div> 

                 <br class="clearer" />

            <?php } ?>

            <div class="inner">

                <div class="panel">

                    <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Footer Panel 1') ) : else : ?>

                        <div class="widget">

                            <h2><?php _e(' Made Magazine ', 'made' ); ?></h2>                           
                            <p><?php _e( "This is a widget panel. To remove this text, login to your WordPress admin panel and go to Appearance >> Widgets, and drag &amp; drop a widget into this widget panel.", 'made' ); ?></p>

                        </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>

                <div class="panel">

                    <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Footer Panel 2') ) : else : ?>

                        <div class="widget">

                            <h2><?php _e(' Made Magazine ', 'made' ); ?></h2>                           
                            <p><?php _e( "This is a widget panel. To remove this text, login to your WordPress admin panel and go to Appearance >> Widgets, and drag &amp; drop a widget into this widget panel.", 'made' ); ?></p>

                        </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>

                <div class="panel">

                    <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Footer Panel 3') ) : else : ?>

                        <div class="widget">

                            <h2><?php _e(' Made Magazine ', 'made' ); ?></h2>                           
                            <p><?php _e( "This is a widget panel. To remove this text, login to your WordPress admin panel and go to Appearance >> Widgets, and drag &amp; drop a widget into this widget panel.", 'made' ); ?></p>

                        </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>

                <div class="panel right">

                    <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Footer Panel 4') ) : else : ?>

                        <div class="widget">

                            <div class="widget">

                            <h2><?php _e(' Made Magazine ', 'made' ); ?></h2>                           
                            <p><?php _e( "This is a widget panel. To remove this text, login to your WordPress admin panel and go to Appearance >> Widgets, and drag &amp; drop a widget into this widget panel.", 'made' ); ?></p>

                        </div>

                        </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>                        

                </div>

                <br class="clearer" />

            </div>

            <div class="copyright">

                <div class="ribbon-shadow-left">&nbsp;</div>

                <div class="floatleft">

                    <?php _e( 'Copyright', 'made' ); ?> &copy; <?php echo date("Y").' '.get_bloginfo('name'); ?>,&nbsp;<?php _e( 'All Rights Reserved.', 'made' ); ?>

                </div>

                <div class="floatright">

                    <div class="floatleft">

                        <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Footer Credits') ) : else : ?>

                            &nbsp;

                        <?php endif; ?> 

                    </div>

                </div>

                <br class="clearer" />

                <div class="ribbon-shadow-right">&nbsp;</div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div> <!--end footer wrapper-->

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>

    <?php echo $oswc_google_analytics; // google analytics code ?>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/plugins.js"></script> <!-- jquery plugin js -->

    <!-- need to setup review category tabs here since we don't know how many review types there are -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict(); 

        //DOCUMENT.READY
        jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
            //loop through each post type and setup a jquery tabs object
            <?php foreach($oswcPostTypes->postTypes as $postType){ ?>
                    jQuery('#tabbed-<?php echo ucwords($postType->name); ?>-reviews > ul').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 150 } });      
            <?php } ?> 

            <?php if($oswc_colorbox) { ?>           
                //colorbox
                jQuery('.review .article-image a').colorbox({transition:'fade', speed:250});
                jQuery('.single-post .content .article-image a').colorbox({transition:'fade', speed:250});
                jQuery('.colorbox').colorbox({transition:'fade', speed:250});
                jQuery('.colorboxiframe').colorbox({transition:'fade', speed:250, iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
                jQuery(".page-content a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']").colorbox(); 
                jQuery('.page-content .gallery a').colorbox({  rel:'gallery' });

            <?php } ?> 
            //initialize smooth div scroll on Don't Miss slider
            jQuery("#dontmiss").smoothDivScroll({ 
                autoScrollingMode: "always", 
                autoScrollingDirection: "endlessloopright", 
                autoScrollingStep: 1, 
                autoScrollingInterval: 50 
            });

            // Logo parade event handlers
            jQuery("#dontmiss").bind("mouseover", function() {
                jQuery(this).smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScrolling");
            }).bind("mouseout", function() {
                jQuery(this).smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
            });

            /* uitotop scroller:
            var defaults = {
                containerID: 'toTop', // fading element id
                containerHoverID: 'toTopHover', // fading element hover id
                scrollSpeed: 1200,
                easingType: 'linear' 
            };
            */

            jQuery().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutExpo' });    

        });

        //the reason they are here instead of in custom.js is because they contain php variables which can't
        //be applied in a .js file. Also, make sure these come before the darken function.

        //WINDOW.LOAD
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
            //spotlight slider  
            jQuery(function() {
                jQuery(".main-content-left #spotlight-slider, .main-content-left #spotlight-slider-responsive").jCarouselLite({     
                    auto: <?php echo $oswc_spotlight_duration; ?>000,
                    easing: "easeInOutExpo",
                    speed: 1100,
                    visible: 2          
                }); 
            });
            jQuery(function() {
                jQuery(".main-content #spotlight-slider, .main-content #spotlight-slider-responsive").jCarouselLite({       
                    auto: <?php echo $oswc_spotlight_duration; ?>000,
                    easing: "easeInOutExpo",
                    speed: 1100,
                    visible: 3          
                }); 
            });     
            //featured slider           
            jQuery('#featured').nivoSlider({                
                effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
                slices: 10, // For slice animations
                boxCols: 6, // For box animations
                boxRows: 3, // For box animations
                animSpeed: 200, // Slide transition speed
                pauseTime: <?php echo $oswc_featured_duration; ?>000, // How long each slide will show
                startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
                directionNav: true, // Next and Prev navigation
                directionNavHide: false, // Only show on hover
                controlNav: false, // 1,2,3... navigation
                controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
                pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
                manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
                prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
                nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
                beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
                afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
                slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
                lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
                afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded                           
            }); 

        });     
    </script>

    <!-- make sure this js file is called after image sliders are setup or else the mosaic and darken effects won't work on hidden image elements-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/custom.js"></script> <!-- made js -->   
    <?php if(!is_front_page() && !is_tax() && !is_category() && !is_tag() && !is_search() && !is_404() && !is_archive() && !is_page_template('template-reviews.php')) { //don't load external javascript for pages that don't use the sharebox?> 
    <?php if($oswc_share_plusone_show) { ?><script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script> <!-- google plus 1 button js --><?php } ?>   
    <?php if($oswc_share_pinterest_show) { ?><script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script> <!-- pinterest share button --><?php } ?>
    <?php if($oswc_share_tumblr_show) { ?><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.tumblr.com/v1/share.js"></script> <!-- tumblr --><?php } ?>
    <?php if($oswc_share_twitter_show) { ?><script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- twitter --><?php } ?>
    <?php if($oswc_share_digg_show) { ?><script src="http://widgets.digg.com/buttons.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- digg --><?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its because jQuery or any js file related to nivoslider is not loading properly. Provide the site link to check that.